# JIRA JQL searching by date - is there a way to exclude today

Tags: sql, jira

e.g.
I'd like to searching the ticket during last 7 day and exclude today.
And following logic is not right. Anyone can help?

> created > startOfDay(-6) AND created != startOfDay(-0d)

Comment: Please include the full code.  JPQL has very little date support.  Typically, you would handle this requirement by binding a `LocalDateTime`, set to today, to a `?` placeholder in the query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude today like:
`created < startOfDay() OR created > startOfDay(1)`

Comment: It works.   created > startOfDay(-6) AND created < startOfDay()

Comment: I have added `created > startOfDay(1) ` because you can want to query `duedate` instead of `created` also.